# Can I say a manifold is partitioned by the basin of attractions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, basins-of-attraction

For smooth continuous dynamical system,

$$\dot{x} = f(x),$$

on manifold $\mathcal{M}$, can I say it is partitioned by countably many basins of attraction?

**Motivation**

I want to prove something which requires the following conjecture

- the manifold associated with the dynamical system can be partitioned by basin of attraction, which constitutes the manifold $\mathcal{M}$ almost everywhere, say if we assume a Lebesgue measure.